# How to insert a component variable value into html src tag using typescript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to add Camera1/2/3/... values to be inserted into HTML form SRC tag. Please check out my code sample for the same. I am using Ionic Framework, Typescript

Typescript:

```
public condicion:boolean;//condicion 

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private contactProvider: ContactProvider, public toastCtrl: ToastController,private smsVar: SMS) {

    this.contactProvider.getAll()
    .then((result) => {
      this.contacts = result;

      let answer = this.contacts.map(x=> {
      let {name2, name3, name4} = x.contact;
      let obj = {name2,name3,name4}
      return obj
    })

    this.GroupKey= answer.map(({ name2}) => name2);
    this.ApiKey= answer.map(({ name4}) => name4);
    this.MonitorId = answer.map(({ name3}) => name3);
    //console.log(answer)
    this.Camara1=this.ApiKey[0]+"/mjpeg/"+this.GroupKey[0]+"/"+this.MonitorId[0];
    this.Camara2=this.ApiKey[1]+"/mjpeg/"+this.GroupKey[1]+"/"+this.MonitorId[1];
    this.Camara3=this.ApiKey[2]+"/mjpeg/"+this.GroupKey[2]+"/"+this.MonitorId[2];
    this.Camara4=this.ApiKey[3]+"/mjpeg/"+this.GroupKey[3]+"/"+this.MonitorId[3];
    console.log(this.Camara1);
    });


  }
```

HTML:

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col>
      <iframe src="http://publicIP:4545/+'Camara1'"  scrolling="no"></iframe>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col>
    <iframe src="http://publicIP:4545/+'Camara2'"  scrolling="no"></iframe>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col>
    <iframe src="http://publicIP:4545/+'Camara3'"  scrolling="no"></iframe>      
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col>
    <iframe src="http://publicIP:4545/+'Camara4'"  scrolling="no"></iframe>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: What is the question or problem?

Comment: His problem is to insert the value of Camara1 Camera2 Camera3 into src tag from this.Camera1/2/3/4 (component) variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest having the `url` as a variable that is passed to your `iframe`. So in your **Typescript** you would have :

```
 const baseUrl = `http://publicIP:4545/`
 // Other code
 ....     
 this.Camara4=this.ApiKey[3]+"/mjpeg/"+this.GroupKey[3]+"/"+this.MonitorId[3];
 this.Camara4Url = `${baseUrl}${this.Camara4}`
```

Then bind it in your **HTML** file:

```
<ion-row>
 <ion-col>
  <iframe [src]="Camara4Url"  scrolling="no"></iframe>
 </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: Bro thanks but I have an error on the html side ERROR Error: "unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)" how I can resolve help me please im too close

Comment: Hey , sure this is handled by Angular's Dom sanitizer https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer so essentially you can pass to `bypassSecurityTrustUrl` function from this module,  the url. This will sanitize the url and make it accessible for images. For everything else you have to check these docs.

Comment: Bro thanks again but now when I whanna see the url on the cell phone gives me a error like this file:///android_asset/www/null it can be load because:

net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND ...... but when I run the app on my pc it works